# How to call different api resource from paging source or remote mediator Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

Hey I want to call two different api for my **Paging Library 3**. I want to ask what is best suit for me to use **Paging Source** or **Remote Mediator**?. What is the use case of both? Can someone please explain me.

**For 1st api call only for single time**

```
@GET("/movie?min=20")
```

Above api call returns this response

```
data class movie(
  var id: Int?,
  var name: String?,
  var items : List<Genre>?
}
```

**Now for 2nd api call its loop to call again and again**

```
@GET("/movie?count=20&&before={time}")
```

Above api call retrun this

```
data class movie(
  var items : List<Genre>?
}
```

**Genre**

```
data class Genre(
   var type: String?,
   var date: String?,
   var cast: String?
}
```

**Genre** have data in both api call. I tried to google this and found this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275353/creating-another-pagingsource-for-a-different-api-resource). But inside this both api return same data. But in my case both returns little bit different. Also **id, name** is only used in **UI** component else list will go to **adapter**. But I didn't understand how to achieved this. I am new in **Flow**, it too difficult to understand, to be honest I am trying to learning [CodeLab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging). Another important thing when 1st time api call, in which the last item contains date will send to 2nd api call in **time** parameter and then 2nd api last item date call again 2nd api, this will go in loop. So how can I track this again in loop condition. **Third** I want to update data at top of list, can we store data in memory than we can update value on that list?  Thanks for advance. Sorry for my wrong english.

**UPDATE**

After @dlam suggestion, I tried to practice some code

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<ActivityViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            viewModel.getMovie().collectLatest {
//                setupAdapter()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**ActivityViewModel**

```
class ActivityViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    fun getMovie(): Flow<PagingData<Genre>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                MultiRequestPagingSource(DataSource())
            }
        ).flow
    }
}
```

**MultiRequestPagingSource**

```
class MultiRequestPagingSource(private val dataSource: DataSource) : PagingSource<String, Genre>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<String, Genre>): String? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<String>): LoadResult<String, Genre> {
        val key = params.key ?: ""

        return try {
            val data = when (params) {
                is LoadParams.Refresh -> {
                    dataSource.fetchInitialMovie()
                }
                is LoadParams.Append -> {
                    dataSource.fetchMovieBefore(key)
                }
                is LoadParams.Prepend -> null
            }

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = data.result,
                prevKey = null,
                nextKey = data?.nextKey,
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error on `data = data.result`

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<TypeVariable(Value)>
Found:
ArrayDeque<Genre>?
```

**DataSource**

```
package com.example.multirequestpaging

class DataSource {

    data class MovieResult(
        val result: ArrayDeque<Genre>?,
        val nextKey: String?
    )

    fun fetchInitialMovie(): MovieResult {
        val response = ApiInterface.create().getMovieResponse(20)

        return MovieResult(
            addInArrayDeque(response),
            response.items?.last()?.date
        )
    }

    fun fetchMovieBefore(key: String): MovieResult {
        val response = ApiInterface.create().getMovieResponseBefore(20, key)

        return MovieResult(
            addInArrayDeque(response),
            response.items?.last()?.date
        )
    }

    private fun addInArrayDeque(response: MovieResponse): ArrayDeque<Genre> {
        val result: ArrayDeque<Genre> = ArrayDeque()
        response.items?.forEach {
            result.add(it)
        }

        return result
    }

}
```

For Full code [Project Link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiRequestPaging)

**1.** I want to add an item to the top of the list. How can I use **invalidate** function? Sorry I didn't understand where I can use.

**2.** I want to use **id,name** in other place so how can i get those variable value in my activity class.

**3.** Is my code structure is good?. Do I need to improved, please give an example. It will also help beginner, who is learning Paging Library.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PagingSource` is the main driver for Paging, it's responsible for loading items that get displayed and represents the single source of truth of data.

`RemoteMediator` is for layered sources, it is essentially a callback which triggers when `PagingSource` runs out of data, so you can fetch from a secondary source. This is primarily useful in cases where you fetching from both DB + Network, where you want locally cached data to power Paging, and then use `RemoteMediator` as a callback to fetch more items into the cache from network.

In this scenario you have two APIs, but they both fetch from the same Network source, so you only need `PagingSource` here. If I'm understanding correctly, you essentially want to call the first API on initial load and the second API on subsequent prepend / append page loads, which you can check / switch on by the type of LoadParams you get. See the subtypes here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource.LoadParams

Comment: yeah trying to learn from site. Can you please give me some example how to do that.

Comment: also how to update data in 0 index which is coming from 1st api call. I mean in Flow

Comment: Do you mean you've loaded the first page, and then want to change the item at index 0? Paging handles this through invalidation + reload. It's very important to do updates this way and maintain a single source of truth so that things like config change are also handled.

Comment: yes i want to do that. Can you please give me example ? I want to learn this amazing library. But i can't find proper way. Thanks

Comment: how can we achieved that storing list in memory. I don't want to store in room or any database.

Comment: You would update the in-memory cache and then call `PagingSource.invalidate`, which triggers Paging to create a new instance of `PagingSource` + `PagingData. Once you call `.submitData` on the newly emitted `PagingData`, loading will restart with the new `PagingSource`.

Comment: do I call `PagingSource.invalidate` in viewmodel ?

Comment: You call it whenever you update your backing dataset (in-memory cache), I would do it directly and immediately if you can, wherever that update happens. It doesn't really matter what layer it happens on, although usually you would do it from your repository layer on any calls to update the cache. (This would also mean your repository produces your `PagingSourceFactory`). There is a nice helper for tracking all PagingSources produced by a factory so you can do this with a single call in `InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory`.

Comment: can I add the **example** + **GitHub** code example, what I understand and you could explain?

Comment: I tried some code. Can you please give me an answer? Thanks

Comment: You cannot directly update Paging's internal in-memory cache of items because it is internal to Paging :). You need to stash the items yourself in your repository, and anytime you update that you should invalidate.

Comment: what do you mean stash the items?